# console gives an error when button is clicked "function is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick"

Tags: javascript

```
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js">
    function ajax_post(){
        loadScript('javascript/jquery-3.2.1.min.js');
        // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
        alert("button clicked");
        // code for modern browsers
        // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
        var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "comments.php";
        var bid='<?php echo $b; ?>';
        var userid='<?php echo $userid; ?>';
        var cm = document.getElementById("latest_comment").value;
        var vars = "your_comment="+cm+"&bookid="+bid+"&uid="+userid;
        hr.open("POST", url, true);
        // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
        hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
        hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
                var return_data = hr.responseText;
                document.getElementById("comment").innerHTML = return_data;
            }
        }
        // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
        hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request
        document.getElementById("comment").innerHTML = "processing...";
    }
     </script>
```

> this is javascript function which should run when i click the csubmit button, but when i click it the console gives an error written in the title. this function has to take the data written in the input tag, go to the comments.php page and insert it in database and display the comments in the comment div
>   I HAVE BEEN STUCK ON THIS ERROR FOR A VERY LONG TIME,BUT NOT ABLE TO FIND WHERE IS THE ERROR

```
<input type="button" id="csubmit" value="SUBMIT" onclick="ajax_post();">
```

Comment: Quick question: the `<script>` is before or after the `<button>`?

Comment: Place your javascript in a new`script` tag. You cannot place the source code in the script tag is it has a source.

Comment: the script tag is before the button

Answer (score 0):

Put `ajax_post` function in other script tag, you can not put `JS` code in script tag which already have `src`

```
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function ajax_post() {
        loadScript('javascript/jquery-3.2.1.min.js');
        // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
        alert("button clicked");
        // code for modern browsers
        // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
        var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "comments.php";
        var bid = '<?php echo $b; ?>';
        var userid = '<?php echo $userid; ?>';
        var cm = document.getElementById("latest_comment").value;
        var vars = "your_comment=" + cm + "&bookid=" + bid + "&uid=" + userid;
        hr.open("POST", url, true);
        // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
        hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
        hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
                var return_data = hr.responseText;
                document.getElementById("comment").innerHTML = return_data;
            }
        }
        // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
        hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request
        document.getElementById("comment").innerHTML = "processing...";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thank you guys, it worked after making some minor changes

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem with your code: Your script is inside a `<script>` tag with a `src` attribute. When a `src` attribute is present, the content inside the `<script>` tag is completely ignored.

This should work:

```
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js">
function ajax_post(){
    loadScript('javascript/jquery-3.2.1.min.js');
    // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
    alert("button clicked");
    // code for modern browsers
    // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "comments.php";
    var bid='<?php echo $b; ?>';
    var userid='<?php echo $userid; ?>';
    var cm = document.getElementById("latest_comment").value;
    var vars = "your_comment="+cm+"&bookid="+bid+"&uid="+userid;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
            document.getElementById("comment").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }
    // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
    hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request
    document.getElementById("comment").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
 </script>
```

Comment: Oh sorry. Something happened and this sent the post before I finished it.

Comment: thanxs man , it worked after some minor changes, #keephelping